# Ambiguous integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, rational-functions

What is the real integral of the function $$f(x) =\frac{1-x^2}{(1 + x^2)^2}$$?

Is it $F_1(x) = \frac{x}{1 + x^2} + C$ or $F_2(x) = \arctan x + C$ ?

The brochure I was reading gave the first result straightaway without any intermediate steps. I went to wolframalpha to try to see what where the steps and to my surprise wolframalpha has [derived the second function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20%7B(x%5E2%20%2B%201)%20%2F%20(x%5E2%20%2B%201)%20%5E%202%7D).

---

I'm terribly sorry. I am preparing for exam non-stop for several days and lost my focus. I probably should go and have some rest.

**Am I required to remove this questions?**

Comment: You've written something different in your link. In the link you've asked wolframalpha to integrate

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2 + 1}{(1+x^2)^2}$$

which have a common factor of $1 + x^2$ in the numerator and denominator, which will cancel and the integral will evaluate to $\arctan(x) + C.$

Comment: You made a typo in WA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$\dfrac{1-x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}=\dfrac{\dfrac1{x^2}-1}{\left(x+\dfrac1x\right)^2}$$

Now $\displaystyle\int\left(\dfrac1{x^2}-1\right)dx=?$

Answer (score 3):

Differentiate both.  You will see $F_1$ works and $F_2$ does not.